# Replace WooCommerce category archive title with image

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

archive-product.php

```
<?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', true ) ) : ?>

        <h1><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php  
        **do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' );**

    ?>
```

*banner is a category image*.

This snippet is used to show an image in a banner location, this worked perfectly  previously, but now I need to add banner on another location and this snippet is showing description as well. If I remove the snippet, the image is also removed.

[image: screenshot]

The other hook I've added is in functions.php

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'woocommerce_category_image', 2 );
function woocommerce_category_image() {

    if ( is_product_category() ){
        global $wp_query;
        $cat = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
        $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
        $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );

        if ( $image ) {
            echo '<div class="gb_coolection_banner"><img class="gb_promo_image" src="' . $image . '" alt="" /></div><div class="'
                    . 'clearboth"></div>' . $cat->description;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code for the woocommerce_archive_description action?

Comment: I've edited the post , please check

Comment: Please edit your title to be descriptive of the actual problem so someone with the same problem might find it in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unhook `woocommerce_product_archive_description` and possibly `woocommerce_product_archive_description` from the `woocommerce_archive_description` hook which is visible in the [`archive-product.php`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/archive-product.php#L41) template.

You would do so using [`remove_action()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action) in your theme's functions.php:

```
function so_31423071_remove_archive_description(){
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description' );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'woocommerce_product_archive_description' );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'so_31423071_remove_archive_description' );
```

Comment: Can you help me locate the woocommerce_archive_description. which file is it in?

Comment: It is in `archive-product.php` as you already posted. Please check my updated answer for how to remove it (and a link to the code source). Posted earlier from the SO app and it is not conducive to writing code.

Answer (score 0):

The $cat->description bit is printing out the text you don't want.  if you still use this function elsewhere you'll need to write another one without that line and call that instead.  Otherwise removing that bit will fix it everywhere the method is called.

Comment: Thank you, I knew about the $cat->description, that is what i want to show and remove the one below which is coming from woocommerce_archive_description

Answer (score 0):

For now I've worked around the problem and made changing in my style.css file to achieve what was required.

Future solutions are still welcome. :)